# populate div by doing math on table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to figure this stuff here out. Can't figure out if it's on the count of me having the numbers in the tds already. Is it takin em in as strings so it don't know how to do the math? I know I got this all wrong, but this is easy stuff I reckon so I hope you can set me straight. Much obliged.

```
<table id="Table">
                <tr>
                <td width="124" style="position: relative" rowspan="4"> 
                    <div id="percentage"></div>
                </td>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td id="Total">259</td>
                <td>Result</td>
                <td id="Count">11</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

JS:

```
var total = $("Total");
var count = $("Count");
var Result = (Count/Total*100);

document.getElementById("percentage").innerHTML =  Result;
```

That didn't work.

Also I need that there Result in .innerHTML to come out as a percentage. Should I just multiply it by 100 like I did here and attach a "%" manually?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? The question isn't tagged with it but the syntax in your example looks like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget '#' to select by Id and you are not convert to int, so you can make it by jQuery in one line:

```
$('#percentage').text(parseInt($('#Count').text())/parseInt($('#Total').text())*100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript is looking for element types instead of the id's change your js to:

```
var total = parseInt($("#Total").text(), 10);
var count = parseInt($("#Count").text(), 10);
var Result = (count/total*100);
```

You are also not converting to a number.

Comment: @BobEnglish If the solution works, you should accept the answer